# DevExpress MVC Grid sorted content to OpenXML

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, openxml, devexpress-mvc

We have an MVC razor view with multiple controls. We need to replicate Razor view layout in Export to Excel content. So I used OpenXML to replicate the view in an Excel.

But now we got a new request to add additional section in the view to display DevExpress MVC Grid.

How can we merge DevExpress MVC Grid sorted/pagination/Filtered content to OpenXML? I have the grid content in a session. But I wanted to display the user selected content (filtered/sorted/pagination) in the UI for this grid.

Can anyone please help me solve the above issue.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I solved my problem using the below process:

I posted the form when user clicks on Export to Excel:

```
$(function () {
        $('a#lkDealExport').click(
            (function (e) {
                var originalAction = $(this).parents('form#DataFrm').attr('action');
                $('form#DataFrm').attr("action", $(e.target).attr("data-formaction"));
                $('form#DataFrm').submit();
                $('form#DataFrm').attr("action", originalAction); // reset the action back to orginal action after the export to excel is executed.
                return false;
            })
            );
    });
```

If we don't post the form, devExpress grid user selection (sorting, pagination and filter) is not exporting to excel.

In post action method, I included the below code:

```
 using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                if (EventListModel.gridData.Count() > 0) // This will avoid exporting header information when search returns 0 results. 
                {
                    GridViewExtension.WriteXlsx(SubmissionGridViewHelper.Instance.Settings, EventListModel.gridData, stream);
                }
```

Then we can pass this MemoryStream to the method that is loading openXML

```
if (eventLogStream.Length > 0) // Insert data into excel only when memory stram is not empty.
            {
                XLWorkbook eventLogWorkBook = new XLWorkbook(eventLogStream);
                var firstPossibleAddres = eventLogWorkBook.Worksheet(1).FirstCellUsed().Address;
                var lastPossibleAddress = eventLogWorkBook.Worksheet(1).LastCellUsed().Address;

                worksheet.Cell(++rowIndex, 1).Value = eventLogWorkBook.Worksheet(1).Range(firstPossibleAddres, lastPossibleAddress).RangeUsed();
                rowIndex += eventLogWorkBook.Worksheet(1).Range(firstPossibleAddres, lastPossibleAddress).RowCount();
            }
```

Hope this will be helpful for others.